# Getting requirements to build wheel ... error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: pip, subprocess

I am trying to install Copernicus Marine Service client (CLI & Python) to download data. So, I follow the instructions on their website and used

`python -m pip install copernicus-marine-client`

but I receive an error during a sub-process.

I work on a Windows 10 PC and a Python 3.12 (64-bit). I install this through running cmd as an administrator. Then, I transfer to the python files by

```
cd C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\
C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312>python -m pip install copernicus-marine-client
Collecting copernicus-marine-client
  Using cached copernicus_marine_client-0.9.11-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (16 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.5 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting boto3<2.0.0,>=1.28.2 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached boto3-1.29.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Collecting cachier<3.0.0,>=2.2.1 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached cachier-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting click<9.0.0,>=8.0.4 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting dask<2023.0.0,>=2022.1.1 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached dask-2022.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting lxml<5.0.0,>=4.9.0 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached lxml-4.9.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting motuclient<2.0.0,>=1.8.4 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached motuclient-1.8.8.tar.gz (30 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting nest-asyncio<2.0.0,>=1.5.8 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.8-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: netCDF4<2.0.0,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\rmd_0\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from copernicus-marine-client) (1.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\rmd_0\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from copernicus-marine-client) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pydap<4.0.0,>=3.2.2 in c:\users\rmd_0\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from copernicus-marine-client) (3.4.1)
Collecting pystac<2.0.0,>=1.8.3 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached pystac-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.27.1 in c:\users\rmd_0\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from copernicus-marine-client) (2.31.0)
Collecting semver<4.0.0,>=3.0.2 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached semver-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.0 kB)
Collecting setuptools<69.0.0,>=68.2.2 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.65.0 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: xarray<2024.0.0,>=2023.9.0 in c:\users\rmd_0\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from copernicus-marine-client) (2023.11.0)
Collecting zarr<3.0.0,>=2.13.3 (from copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached zarr-2.16.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.5->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.5->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.5->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.2.tar.gz (184 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.5->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.0.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.5->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.33.0,>=1.32.3 (from boto3<2.0.0,>=1.28.2->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached botocore-1.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3<2.0.0,>=1.28.2->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 (from boto3<2.0.0,>=1.28.2->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached s3transfer-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting watchdog (from cachier<3.0.0,>=2.2.1->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached watchdog-3.0.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (82 kB)
Collecting portalocker (from cachier<3.0.0,>=2.2.1->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached portalocker-2.8.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.5 kB)
Collecting pathtools (from cachier<3.0.0,>=2.2.1->copernicus-marine-client)
  Using cached pathtools-0.1.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2jfegw2x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2jfegw2x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2jfegw2x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\rmd_0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2jfegw2x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 2):

From Copernicus' installation page: "The Copernicus Marine Toolbox works with version of Python >= 3.9 and <3.12." (https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/7970514-copernicus-marine-toolbox-installation)

You cannot install the marine toolbox with version 3.12. This is because their toolbox is dependent on the pathtools package, and pathtools cannot be used in 3.12 (see here: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/pathtools/issues/13)

I suggest installing a previous version of python for now, hopefully someone will update the pathtools package so we can use the toolbox in 3.12.